# How to send SMS or Push Notifications to million records with PHP

Tags: php, random, forum

I am new to this mobile technology and in PHP. I have about two or two and half records where I have to send SMSs as well as push notifications on the mobiles. With PHP, i have tried with simple looping technique, but it seems it is not the right way as some times SMSs are missed from the number. Also, don't want to use third party APIs.

I want to have some ideas how to deal this records with PHP script. here is the sudo code

```
$mobilenumbers = array("1","2","3",........."2500000");


foreach($mobilenumbers as $val){    
    $flag = $this->sendSms($val);
}

function sendSms($mobileNumber){

    Send SMS to Mobile Number

}
```

So, here foreach loop does many skips.

Comment: Okaay.. you don't want to use API's and you're not showing any code. Can I ask you this: How can we, answer the unanswerable? Learn [ask] questions on [so]

Comment: this is general scenario. let me write sudo code.

Comment: you have a sms gateway right?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know the basic code to send the notification to android and ios device by PHP. you need to know only that how you can send it to multiple devices. 
It really took too much time if you sending it with PHP. Because for android each channel request must not have more than 1000 devices. 
and for IOS, you have to request for each device, it also provides support to send notifications to multiple devices at a time,  but the possibilities of failure cases is higher than to send it for single. if you want to send the notification to multiple devices at a time and one device id is wrong over there then it will close the channel for the remaining devices.